# Oracle SQL loader control file creation for date and time

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am using below CTL file to load data into table

```
Load data
Append
Into table abc
Fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'

Trailing nullcols
(
R_date date 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'
)
```

Csv file value is as

```
R_date
09/12/2023 12:30:34
08/11/2023 22;30:45
```

In table abc r_date column datatype is date.

> Ora-01840 input value not long enough for date format.

Noting we have written in above file

Comment: Please help to insert data into data

Comment: Does really the file have `08/11/2023 22;30:45` with a semi-colon or it's just a typo ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
R_date date "mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss"
```